# Bot Conversation Builder

Tags: botframework

My company is evaluating Bot frameworks. Each vendor we demoed with so far has shown some great visual tools to build conversations workflows. Is there a similar tool offered by MicroSoft?

Comment: [so] is not the right place to ask about tool recommendations.

Comment: You might want to check out the software recommendations section on stack exchange for something like this.

Comment: I have but couldn't find it. MicroSoft has introduced the Bot Framework for developers and we are able to build the bot, but without some visual tools it's a hard sell to business.

Comment: `MicroSoft has introduced the Bot Framework for developers and we are able to build the bot, but without some visual tools it's a hard sell to business.` You bot can be connected to channels or emulator, which would help show conversations between bot and clients.

Comment: As Fei Han indicates, you can use a tool like the [Bot Framework Emulator](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/tree/v4) which has recently undergone a large amount of change. You can find an overview of the changes in this [Channel 9 vid](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/AI-Show/Meet-the-New-Bot-Framework-Emulator).

Comment: I think I framed my question wrong. I am not talking about tools to test the bot, such as Emulator, but a visual conversation builder, where I can instruct the bot on how to respond to certain questions, how to guide conversation, etc.

Comment: `a visual conversation builder, where I can instruct the bot on how to respond to certain questions, how to guide conversation, etc.` As far as I know, there is no such tool currently.